# eclipse-plugins "JSHint' startup too slow

Tags: javascript, eclipse-plugin

Every time i startup eclipse, the '[JSHint Problem Check](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aDNh6.png)e' will cost a lot of time

Comment: Whats you question? How to disable JSHint? might want to elaborate

Comment: when i startup eclipse,i have to wait the progress-"JSHint Problem Checker" about 20 minutes ,i want to konw why this happen and how to solve it.thank you very much !